# howto: limit movies displayed in itunes "in-app" movies folder to those in the itunes library

Tags: itunes

Itunes adds all movies to my itunes movies folder (not the actual folder in the filesystem, but the one inside itunes), including movies from trash and personal stuff I don't want in itunes. How can I limit the movies itunes display to the one's that are actually added to the library and/or "reside" in specific folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*iTunes* is going to display any files that are in its library. To avoid displaying files, don't import them into iTunes and don't use iTunes as the player for those files because they will be added to the library collection. To play those files use *Quicktime Player* or a third-party solution like [*VLC*](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) instead.

You can also disable *iTunes*'s copying of files into it's own folder structure in **iTunes > Preferences > Advanced**, but this will apply to all media types and, in my experience, is a less-than-optimal way to use *iTunes*.

[image: screenshot of iTunes Advance Preferences tab]